# $('body').click function is working before Datepicker (jquery) beforeShow method

Tags: jquery, datepicker, onselect

$('body').click function is working before Datepicker (jquery) beforeShow method.
How can I trigger first   onselect method of Datepicker (jquery). I mean

```
   $('body').click(function (evt) {

    // do something
    }

 $('#UxDatePickerFrom').datetimepicker({

beforeShow: function (inst) {
                // do something on select
            })
```

but if I select datepicker , body click is working first which is unwanted.

Comment: That does not look like the [jquery datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers fire in the order that they are registered. If you want the body `click` handler to fire after the datetime picker shows, reverse the order you instantiate them:

```
$('#UxDatePickerFrom').datetimepicker({
    onSelect: function (inst) {
        // do something on select
    }
});

$('body').click(function (evt) {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('body').click();` is a global click handler for all the elements with it, so where ever you click on the body or on the date picker the function will execute.

Your solution is to change the click handler to affect more specialized group of elements and not all of it.

```
$("#yourspecificelement").click(function() {
    // ....
});
```